# How to compute these GCD's?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, contest-math

Please suggest me how to compute the GCD of theese really big numbers :

1. GCD of $2^{120547564397}-1$ and $2^{356946681940}-1$
2. GCD of $2^n-1$ and $n!$ where $n=3^{19}$

Thanks to [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20127/how-to-compute-these-gcds/20130#20130) I understood that the first problem could be solved by the property that $gcd(f(m), f(n)) = f(gcd(m,n))$ if $ f(n) \equiv f(n-m) (mod\ f(m)),\ \ \ f(0)\ =\ 0$.

Any hints for the second one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT** $\rm\ (2^a-1,\:2^b-1)\ =\ 2^{(a,b)}-1\ $ where $\rm\ (a,b) := gcd(a,b)\:.\ $ For proofs see [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1/11636#11636) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1/11636#11636) - which has a polynomial analog.

Comment: And what exactly $2^{(a,b)}-1$ means here ?

Comment: $(a,b)$ is the GCD of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus:Thanks that's helps for the first one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the second one is only going to be possible to find computationally (although feel free to prove me wrong).  The primes dividing Mersenne numbers are difficult to guess -- so we can't exclude some prime $p<n$ from dividing $2^n-1$ without testing (although, of course we can exclude every $p>n$).

So, for each prime $p<n$ we can find the largest $x$ such that $p^x$ divides both $n!$ and $2^n-1$, then combine the results using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Some tips:

- The largest $a$ such that $p^a$ divides $n!$ is $a=\sum_{k \geq 1} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor$.
- Then we can use [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to reduce the amount of computation required to find $2^n-1 \pmod {p^a}$ (or if you use some computer algebra system it'll do this for you).

There's approximately 60 million primes to process, so it will take a while, but it's not out-of-the-question.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, your second question [came up here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/efficient-method-to-compute-mathrmgcd2n-1-n) a couple of days ago. I answered it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/efficient-method-to-compute-mathrmgcd2n-1-n/20038#20038). Perhaps $n=3^{19}$ is too large to make this method practical, but Douglas explains how to do without using $N$.